# Translate the XAML code into C# hidden code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockOuter" Background="White">
        <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockCue" Background="White">
            <ScrollBar Name="hscroll" 
      DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
      Orientation="Horizontal" 
      Minimum="-360" Maximum="360" 
      LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />
            <ScrollBar Name="vscroll" 
      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
      Orientation="Vertical"
      Minimum="-360" Maximum="360" 
      LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />
            <Viewport3D Margin="0" Name="viewCube">
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup x:Name="group">
                            <!--Ligthts-->
                            <AmbientLight Color="Gray" /> 
                            <DirectionalLight Color="gray" Direction="1,-2,-3" />
                            <DirectionalLight Color="Gray" Direction="-1,2,3" />

                        </Model3DGroup>

                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>

                <Viewport3D.Camera>

                    <PerspectiveCamera
                      Position = "5, 5, 5"
                      LookDirection = "-5, -5, -5"
                      UpDirection = "0, 1, 0"
                      FieldOfView = "60">

                        <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                            <Transform3DGroup>
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                          Axis="0 1 0" 
                                          Angle="{Binding ElementName=hscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                          Axis="1 0 0" 
                                          Angle="{Binding ElementName=vscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                            </Transform3DGroup>
                        </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>

                    </PerspectiveCamera>
                </Viewport3D.Camera>
            </Viewport3D>

        </DockPanel>     
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The C#:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private GeometryModel3D mGeometry;
        private double a = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buildCube();
        }
        private void buildCube()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                a += 0.1;

                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(a, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(a, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(a, 1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(a, 1, 1));

                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);

                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);

                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\junqi\Desktop\1.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();
                group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all of the code.

I want to make a 3D cube using many pictures, this program just uses a picture to build this. I want to use pictures in a file, and according the number of a pictures to create the cube.

after I used Colon Smith's code , I find a problem that in Xaml this code is very good,the following picture will show result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SazYw.png)
 but when I use C#  there is a problem when  I runing  this code .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ1Mx.png)

the problem is Invalid URI.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    GeometryModel3D model3d = new GeometryModel3D(); // you will already have created this...just use the reference to your own "GeometryModel3D" object

    BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"E:\2.jpg"));
    Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
    model3d.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(brush);
```

Or this:

```
    BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\2.jpg"));
    Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
    Geometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
    Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();
    GeometryModel3D mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
    mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();   
    group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
```

This shows you how to do it either all in XAML, or with code-behind. You could build up the cube in different ways e.g. could could create the same face 4 times and rotate by 90degrees each time...then create the 2 end faces...however....I think it's simpler just to do it in this natural way for clarity.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockOuter" Background="White">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click">Load</Button>
            <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockCue" Background="White">
                <ScrollBar Name="hscroll" 
      DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
      Orientation="Horizontal" 
      Minimum="-360" Maximum="360" 
      LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />
                <ScrollBar Name="vscroll" 
      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
      Orientation="Vertical"
      Minimum="-360" Maximum="360" 
      LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />
                <Viewport3D Margin="0" Name="viewCube">
                    <ModelVisual3D>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <Model3DGroup x:Name="group">
                                <!--Ligthts-->
                                <AmbientLight Color="Yellow" />
                                <DirectionalLight Color="gray" Direction="1,-2,-3" />
                                <DirectionalLight Color="Gray" Direction="-1,2,3" />
                                <!-- 1-top -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,-1 -1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\1.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- 2-front -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,1 -1,1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\2.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- 3-right -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "1,-1,1 1,-1,-1 1,1,-1 1,1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\3.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- 4-left -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,-1 -1,-1,1 -1,1,1 -1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\4.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- 5-back -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1 1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\5.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- 6-bottom -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,-1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,1 -1,-1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0,1,2 2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="s:\6.jpg"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                            </Model3DGroup>

                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>

                    <Viewport3D.Camera>

                        <PerspectiveCamera
                      Position = "5, 5, 5"
                      LookDirection = "-5, -5, -5"
                      UpDirection = "0, 1, 0"
                      FieldOfView = "60">

                            <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                                <Transform3DGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                          Axis="0 1 0" 
                                          Angle="{Binding ElementName=hscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                          Axis="1 0 0" 
                                          Angle="{Binding ElementName=vscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                </Transform3DGroup>
                            </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>

                        </PerspectiveCamera>
                    </Viewport3D.Camera>
                </Viewport3D>
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buildCube()
        {
            group.Children.Clear(); // clear out the existing geometry XAML

            // Lights

            group.Children.Add(new AmbientLight(Colors.Gray));
            group.Children.Add(new DirectionalLight(Colors.Gray, new Vector3D(1, -2, -3)));
            group.Children.Add(new DirectionalLight(Colors.Gray, new Vector3D(-1, 2, 3)));

            // Top
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, -1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\1.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }

            // Front
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, 1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\2.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }

            // Right
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, 1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\3.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }

            // Left
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, -1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\4.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }

            // Back
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, 1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 1, -1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\5.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }

            // Bottom
            {
                MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, -1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, -1, 1));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-1, -1, 1));
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
                mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 1));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(1, 0));
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"S:\6.jpg"));
                Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage);
                GeometryModel3D geommodel3d = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush));
                group.Children.Add(geommodel3d);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            buildCube();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: there is a problem when I run this code:Brush brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapimage); ,   
An exception of type "System.NullReferenceException" occurred in WpfApplication3.exe but was not processed in user code .   
Additional information: An object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I have a  MeshGeometry3D object  mesh, now I want  to make GeometryModel3D object  mGeometry to have a picture as it's matrial, 
before your code  I use follow codes:   mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.YellowGreen));
   mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup(); //group is a Model3DGroup object
   group.Children.Add(mGeometry);  ,now i want  to use a picture to repelace Brushes.YellowGreen.

Comment: Have you got the image where you said it was? namely at "e:\2.jpg" ?

Comment: when I use this code ,there is nothing showed in output window,  do you have wechat ? I can give you my code.

Comment: copy and paste your xaml and other code....probably something like you haven't set a size for element you have used your geomemtry on

Comment: comment have limits ,I can't copy and paste my all code , do you have other Contact information？

Comment: add it into the quesiton

Comment: ok, i have added these code in question,please to check this code ,thanks.

Comment: after I use your code ,I find a problem,when I use xaml code ,the result is very good ,but when I use C# code，there is a problem when code running the code :BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"‪E:\image\1.jpg"));  the description is Invalid URI.

Comment: I found that the problem when I copied the path from the image's properties ， the path was not available .when I entered it manually, the path was available

Comment: Thank you very much Colin Smith ! with your help I finish my final goal